# using variables in subprocess.run

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run a Linux curl command in python using `subprocess.run`.

This code runs perfectly in the command line:

```
curl -F file=@$filename -F "initial_comment=$logo detected" -F channels=test -H "Authorization: Bearer xoxp-1638450445057-1631984334692-2039667356465-c7687a36843591bd232ac7b641ef83c1" https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

When i try to run it within my python script using `subprocess.run`,

```
subprocess.run(["curl", "-F", "file=$filename", "-F", "\"initial_comment=$logo_detected\"", "-F", "channels=test", "-H", "\"Authorization: Bearer xoxp-1638450445057-1631984334692-2039667356465-c7687a36843591bd232ac7b641ef83c1\"", "https://slack.com/api/files.upload"])
```

I get an error:

```
Warning: setting file {filename}  failed!
curl: (26) read function returned funny value
```

Edit: I get this error too: `curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer`.

Edit2: I have also tried to set `shell=True` but I got the same error as above.

```
subprocess.run("curl -F file=@$filename -F \"initial_comment=meWATCH logo\" -F channels=test -H \"Authorization: Bearer xoxp-1638450445057-1631984334692-2039667356465-c7687a36843591bd232ac7b641ef83c1\" https://slack.com/api/files.upload", shell=True)
```

Comment: You don't need to escape spaces when using `shell=False`, and don't need to separate the arguments if using `shell=True`

Comment: What is the output of the command when run on the Command Line

Comment: @Sagar it is a json output when run on the command line

Comment: @mousetail i don't get when you mean. Is there anything wrong with my subprocess.run command?

Answer (score 2):

Since `subprocess.run` is run by Python *without* an intermediate shell, it does not understand variable, interpolation or other notation of shells or other languages. Use Python variables, interpolation and notation:

```py
#                                                      v items delimited via list instead of quoting
subprocess.run(["curl", "-F", f"file=@{filename}", "-F", f"initial_comment={logo_detected}", ...])
#                             ^ string formatting to insert variables
```

---

When referring to *environment* variables in specific, use `os.environ` to access them:

```py
filename, logo_detected = os.environ["filename"], os.environ["logo_detected"]
subprocess.run(["curl", "-F", f"file=@{filename}", "-F", f"initial_comment={logo_detected}", ...])
```

Comment: I am getting a KeyError from this.

Comment: @user15838691 Keep in mind I am left guessing what kind of variables your bash code is referring to. When ``os.environ`` gives a KeyError, that means either you *did not* intend to use environment variables but forgot to declare them in Python and should just use that directly, or you *did* intend to use environment variables and forgot to declare them in the parent program – e.g. via ``export filename`` in bash.

Comment: filename and logo_detected contains a string declared in Python. I am trying to pass this two variables to my subprocess.run command.

Comment: Then just don't use the ``... = os.environ ...`` bits. They are only needed to load a variable from the environment.

Comment: In that case, running the command ```subprocess.run(["curl", "-F", f"file=@{filename}", "-F", f"initial_comment={logo_detected}", ...])``` would work but i am getting a error: curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

(Sorry I am new to this.)

Comment: @user15838691 I'm afraid that seems to be specific to curl, not the code itself. There is a [github issue](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/3206) which suggests the culprit is the server, though.

Comment: If it is a curl error, does this mean that there is no problem with my code? However, when i tried to run the exact same code in the command line (not using Python's subprocess.run, it returns a proper json output i am expecting and not a curl error. Can i say that this curl command i am trying to run is not supported (not sure what the correct term is) in python?

Comment: @user15838691 If it's working fine on the shell, it will work fine in Python as well – if translated properly. ``curl`` is just a subprocess in either case, it doesn't "know" who called it. Are you passing all parameters correctly? In specific, did you unescape the ``Authorization`` to not start/end with ``\"`` just how I removed that from ``initial_comment``? It should just be ``"Authorization: ...c1"`` not ``"\"Authorization: ...c1\""``.

Comment: This is the comment i am running on shell ```curl -F file=@$filename -F "initial_comment=$logo detected" -F channels=test -H "Authorization: Bearer xoxp-1638450445057-1631984334692-2039667356465-c7687a36843591bd232ac7b641ef83c1" https://slack.com/api/files.upload``` and this is the command i am running on python ```subprocess.run(["curl", "-F", f"file=@$filename", "-F", f"initial_comment=$logo_detected detected", "-F", "channels=test", "-H", "Authorization: Bearer xoxp-1638450445057-1631984334692-2039667356465-c7687a36843591bd232ac7b641ef83c1", "https://slack.com/api/files.upload"])```

Comment: And when i run my command in python, i am getting this error `Warning: setting file $filename  failed!
curl: (26) read function returned funny value`

Comment: As far as I can tell, you should use ``subprocess.run(["curl", "-F", f"file=@{filename}", "-F", f"initial_comment={logo_detected detected}", "-F", "channels=test", "-H", "Authorization: Bearer xoxp-1638450445057-1631984334692-2039667356465-c7687a36843591bd232ac7b641ef83c1", "https://slack.com/api/files.upload"])``. Note the ``{...}`` instead of ``$...``.